# Ajax - дождаться ответа

Tags: ajax, javascript

Доброго дня товарищи! Я знаю **ajax** и **javascript** по мере в нём необходимости и теперь передо мной встала следующая задача :

**Ajax** отправляет асинхронный запрос, который не тормозит весь сценарий на время выполнения запроса и выводит результат по его готовности. Пишется регистрация, формы которой**(email, login, password и т.д.)** будут проверяться сначала **javascript**'ом, а после через **ajax** - **PHP** сценарием.

**Задача :** выполнить проверку форм, и если хотя-бы одна из проверок сообщила о неудаче, то не дать нажать на кнопку "**зарегистрироваться**". Но дело в том, что "**всеобщая проверка**" запускается при нажатии на кнопу "**зарегистрироваться**" и она не сработает, ибо **ajax** даст ответ не сразу, а по готовности.

**Вопрос :** можно ли заставить **ajax** задержать выполнения сценария, фактически затормозить обозреватель до тех пор, пока не будет получен результат запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но дело в том, что "всеобщая проверка" запускается при нажатии на кнопу "зарегистрироваться" и она не сработает, ибо `ajax` даст ответ не сразу, а по готовности.

> запускается при нажатии на кнопу
> "зарегистрироваться"

1. а почему бы не повешать проверку на изменение полей пароля и т.д., вместо кнопки "зарегиться"
2. почему бы изначально сделать кнопку не активной, а как придет запрос после изменения полей активировать ее

Comment: Вариант достойный, как называют событие, которое реагирует на изменение поля, а не на нажатую клавишу? Ведь кто-то может просто "вставить" туда текст.

Comment: событие oninput подходит лучше всего, про старые браузеры подсказать не смогу